# Calculate minimal Variance

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

My task is to calculate the minimal variance. I got a result, but don't know for sure if it's correct. Maybe some of you could help me out here.

Let $X$ be some real-valued random variable. We know for sure that $P(X=10)=P(X=20)=\frac{1}{3}$. Calculate the minimal variance.

So i did the following:

$E(X^2) = \dots + \dots + 10^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \dots + 20^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \dots \geq 10^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + 20^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \approx 166.67$ and

$E(X)^2 = (\dots + \dots + 10 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \dots + 20 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \dots)^2 \geq (10 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + 20 \cdot \frac{1}{3})^2 = 100$, therefore by

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \geq 166.67 - 100 = 66.67$

It this how it's done? I do really want to understand the concept.

Comment: Easiest way to reduce variance is to put everything you can right at the mean.  Here, for example, suppose $P(X=15)=\frac 13$.  Variance in that case is a lot lower than $66.67$!

Comment: Also, note that $A≥Y$ and $B≥Z$ does not imply that $A-B≥Y-Z$.

Comment: Note that if $\Pr(X=15)=\frac{1}{3}$  then the variance is $\frac{50}{3}$.

Comment: Hi @lulu, thanks i do see now that the last step is not true. (i.e. $2 \geq 1 \land 4 \geq 2$ does not imply $-2 = 2-4 \geq 1-2 = -1$) I'm really unfamiliar with this topic, how would one "put everything at the mean"? Any hint will help.

Comment: I gave you the actual distribution!  Just take $P(X=15)=\frac 13$.  Then that term contributes $0$ to the variance, and a quick computation shows that $(A-\mu)^2+(B-\mu)^2$ is minimized when $\mu = \frac {A+B}2$.

Comment: Hi @lulu , i see, so i would just assume $P(X=10)=P(X=15)=P(X=20)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $P(X=i) = 0 \forall i \notin \{ 10,15,20 \}$ and therefore $E(X)=15$ and $E(X)^2 = 225$ and $E(X^2) \approx 241.67$ and therefore $Var(X) \geq 16.67$?

Comment: You should prove that this distribution gives the minimum.  I don't believe it helps to introduce $E[X]$ (though maybe I am wrong).  Just do it from the definition of variance.  Like I say, $(10-\mu)^2+(20-\mu)^2$ is minimized by taking $\mu=15$.  Therefore, the min-variance distribution must have mean $15$.  Furthermore, if there was some other value $A\neq 15$ with positive probability, $(A-15)^2$ would increase the variance.  (if it is a continuous distribution, you need to argue the same way for some interval not containing $15$.)

Comment: Hi @lulu , thanks a lot! Last request: Would you mind copy your last comment as answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometrically, the idea is to simply put the other values of $X$ at the mean ($15$). In this case, we simply declare that $P(X=15)=\frac 13$.  Thus our candidate distribution has $X=10,15,20$ each with probability $\frac 13$.  To see that this gives the minimum variance:

First note:  for general $A,B$ the expression $(A-\mu)^2+(B-\mu)^2$ is minimized when $\mu =\frac {A+B}2$, so $\mu$ is the average of $A,B$.  This follows at once by differentiating the expression in $\mu$.

Thus, if your distribution has any mean other that $15$ we see that it's variance must exceed the variance of our candidate.

Likewise, if $A$ is any value other than $10,15,20$ with $P(X=A)>0$ the term $(A-15)^2$ will contribute to the variance, and hence this distribution will have greater variance than ours.  A similar argument for continuous distributions shows that if we have  $[a,b]$ containing none of $10,15,20$ then $P(X\in [a,b])=0$ and we are done.